# Compute number of floats in a int range - Python

Tags: python, pandas, count, range

I've the following dataframe containing floats as input and would like to compute how many values are in range 0;90 and 90;180. The output dataframe was obtained using frequency() function from excel.

[Input dataframe]

[image: 1]

[Desired output]

[image: 2]

I'd like to do the same thing with python but didn't find a solution. Do you have any suggestion ?

I can also provide source files if needed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just to confirm, does `87,084` in your dataframe mean `87.084`, as floats in Python use a `.`?

Comment: Yes 87,084 = 87.084 forgot to change decimal separator to UK/US Standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way, by dividing the columns by 90, then using `groupy` and `count`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [
        [87.084,5.293],
        [55.695,0.985],
        [157.504,2.995],
        [97.701,179.593],
        [97.67,170.386],
        [118.713,177.53],
        [99.972,176.665],
        [124.849,1.633],
        [72.787,179.459]
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Var1','Var2'])
df = (df / 90).astype(int)
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["0-90"], ["90-180"]])
df1['Var1'] = df.groupby('Var1').count()
df1['Var2'] = df.groupby('Var2').count()
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
        0  Var1  Var2
0    0-90     3     4
1  90-180     6     5
```